# How to get variables outside for loop in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to access the variables "onlinehub" and "offlinehub" outside for loop, but the variables prints only the initial declaration values. Is there any other way to do it?

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  client.keys('hub*', function (err, keys) {
    console.log(keys.length);
    for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
    client.hgetall(keys[i], function(err, reply) {
    if(reply.status == "online"){
      onlinehub++;
    }
    else if(reply.status == "offline"){
      offlinehub++;
    }
  });
  }
    // for (var i=0; i<reply.length; i++){
    //   console.log(reply.id)
    // }
    console.log(onlinehub +"-" +offlinehub)

    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can make two global variable   and assign them a value of onlinehub and use them outside of for loop.

```
var global_onlinehub=0;
var global_offlinehub=0;
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
client.keys('hub*', function (err, keys) {
console.log(keys.length);

for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
client.hgetall(keys[i], function(err, reply) {
if(reply.status == "online"){
 global_onlinehub= onlinehub++;
}
else if(reply.status == "offline"){
  global_offlinehub=offlinehub++;
}
});
}
// for (var i=0; i<reply.length; i++){
//   console.log(reply.id)
// }
console.log(global_onlinehub +"-" +global_offlinehub)

});
});
```